# Python module variable in __init__.py

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I create a module with one function (read_file) which read a file and add data in one dict (DATA).

The goal is to have access to the dict (DATA) everywhere in other modules, but with only one call to the function read_file. I need this module compatible with python2 and Python3

The tree is :

```
Config\
    __init__.py
    config.py
OtherModule\
    __init__.py
    module1.py
    module2.py
```

The code are:

```
 Config
 ==== __init__.py ====
 from config.config import read_file
 DATA = dict()

 ==== config.py ====
 import config
 def read_file(param):
    ....
    config.DATA = (depend of param)

OtherModule
==== module1.py =====
import config
config.read_file(param)

==== module2.py =====
import config
print(config.DATA) -> Empty
import module2
print(config.DATA) -> NotEmpty
```

The question is why this works very fine in python3 but it's always empty in python2 ?

I know I can pass with another module, like config.varaible.DATA but I would like to not do it. It is possible ?

I using python2.7 et python 3.6

Comment: That's strange... `module2` isn't even importing `config`, and even so, it can see it? Is this all the code?

Comment: I do the correction. Thanks. This is just a very simple example of what I need.

Comment: So, you are import `config` in the module `config` itself?
Also, what is your pythonpath here? 
How is it possible you are importing config in `module1` and `module2` ?

Comment: I need to import config in the module itself to have access to DATA. It's the same in module1 and module2. The goal is to have a package (no modification of PythonPath)